# Redirect addon domains with/to HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

There is one Domain:

- `maindomain.com`

And 3 addon domains:

- `addondomain.com`
- `addon-domain.com`
- `addondomain.net`

My goal is to redirect every domain to `https://www.maindomain.com`

This is what I tried (`.htaccess`):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^(?:www\.)?(addondomain|addon-domain)\.com$|^(?:www\.)?addondomain\.net$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.maindomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

Or this (`.htaccess`):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.?addondomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www\.maindomain\.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.?addon-domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www\.maindomain\.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.?addondomain\.net[NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www\.maindomain\.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.maindomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This works if for example `www.addondomain.com` or `addondomain.com` is entered as URL. But if someone types `https://www.addondomain.com` the notice "this connection is not secure" appears.

Do I have to apply for a SSL-Certificate for every addon-domain to make it work? Or is there something wrong in my `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to apply for a SSL-Certificate for every addon-domain to make it work?

Yes. The SSL handshake (and *browser error*) occurs at the very start of the request, before your server (and your `.htaccess` code) is able to process the request.

Note that this doesn't necessarily mean installing a new SSL cert for each domain. You can get multi-domain/SAN certs - which are supported by all modern browsers.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.?addondomain\.com [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www\.maindomain\.com/$1 [R=301,L]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.?addon-domain\.com [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www\.maindomain\.com/$1 [R=301,L]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.?addondomain\.net[NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www\.maindomain\.com/$1 [R=301,L]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.maindomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
> ```

Incidentally, you don't need the first three rule blocks. The last one is sufficient. But remove the `NC` flag on the *negated* condition. (You were also missing a space before the flags on the 3rd rule). In other words:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.maindomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.maindomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```